# InvalidResourceName error while writing parquet file in ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am reading a csv file and writing the same in parquet format  in ADLS Gen2 using ADF copy activity.

My source:

[image]

My Sink :

[image]

I am facing the below error :

```
Failure type
User configuration issue


Details
ErrorCode=AdlsGen2OperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'. Account: 'adlsedmadifpoc'. FileSystem: 'raw_area'. ErrorCode: 'InvalidResourceName'. Message: 'The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.'. RequestId: '70d7xbfd-6xxf-00ec-2c74-9axxxx000000'. TimeStamp: 'Thu, 26 Aug 2021 12:19:56 GMT'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No. I followed the conventions mentioned in MS website. Getting the same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when there are characters introduced to the Container Name which do not follow the Azure storage  [container naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata#container-names).

The best way to avoid this error is to copy it as it is from the Azure environment.

A container name must contain valid characters, conforming to the following naming rules:

- All letters  **must be lowercase.**
- Names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.
- Names must start or end with a letter or number.
- Names can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
- Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.